# Cloning of a div in javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I want to clone a div by clicking on ADD link. But when a div gets cloned then a new cloned div ADD link is not behaving like the previous ADD link. I want to achieve this functionality. Please help.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototyp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add_option").click(function(){
          console.log("clicked !");
          $('<div id="cloned">\n\
            <input type="checkbox" >\n\
            <input type="text"> \n\
            <a href="#" ><span >ADD </span></a> \n\
            <a href="#" class="remove-option"><span> REMOVE</span></a>\n\
            </div>').clone().appendTo('#cloned');
          $('span').addClass('add_option');
        });
      });
    </script>
    
    <div id="cloned">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="text">
      <a href="#"><span  class="add_option">ADD</span></a>
      <a href="#" class="remove-option"><span>REMOVE</span></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id` attribute should be one. is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("body").on('click','.add_option',function () {

                 console.log("clicked !");
            $('<div id="cloned">\n\
    <input type="checkbox" >\n\
    <input type="text"> \n\
    <a href="#" ><span >ADD </span></a> \n\
    <a href="#" class="remove-option"><span> REMOVE</span></a>\n\
    </div>').clone().appendTo('#cloned');
            $('span').addClass('add_option');
        });
            });
```

**NOTE:** Also the Ids you give to your elements should be unique, As in your case the same id is passed to every `div` that you clone!

Comment: What do I do to achieve the same functionality to delete a div.

Comment: you could use use remove() function of jquery

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
         $("body").on('click','.add_option',function (){
             console.log("clicked !");
        $('<div id="cloned">\n\
<input type="checkbox" >\n\
<input type="text"> \n\
<a href="" ><span >ADD </span></a> \n\
<a href="" ><span> REMOVE</span></a>\n\
</div>').clone().appendTo('#cloned');
        $('span').addClass('add_option');
    });
    $("body").on('click','.remove_option',function (){
        $('#cloned').remove();
        });
        });

Comment: I have done it like this and it removes all the divs which having id = 'clone' .

Comment: off course it would! dont give them same id, give them unique ids

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes:

- replace `id` to `class`. then, use `$('.cloned')`.
- move `add_option` class name to `<a href="#" class="add_option"><span>ADD</span></a>`
- when you click `a` use `return false`
- just use to copy this code `$('.cloned:last').after($('.cloned:last').clone());`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript prototype</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototyp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".add_option", function () {
        console.log("clicked !");
        $('.cloned:last').after($('.cloned:last').clone());
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".remove-option", function () {
        $(this).closest(".cloned").remove();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


<div class="cloned">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text">
<a href="#" class="add_option"><span>ADD</span></a>
<a href="#" class="remove-option"><span>REMOVE</span></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hey Can I add you in my friend list on gmail / fb ?

Comment: Your answer is awesome, I am very thankful of you.. If youdon't mind, please add me on aryanpra16dec@gmail.com for both gmail/fb.